# Shiny R recordPlot() renders locally but object does not display on Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

my server.r ->

```
output$finaltable2 <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$check)) {return()}
    else
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Q Bins", renderPlot(replayPlot(qplot), height = 600)),
        tabPanel("P Value Histogram", renderPlot(replayPlot(tplot), height = 600)),
        tabPanel("Q Value to Use", h3(toString(qaverage)))
  )
```

})

Taking out the `replayPlot()` and just calling the qplot/tplot object within a `renderPlot()` also works:

```
output$finaltable2 <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$check)) {return()}
    else
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Q Bins", renderPlot(qplot, height = 600)),
        tabPanel("P Value Histogram", renderPlot(tplot, height = 600)),
        tabPanel("Q Value to Use", h3(toString(qaverage)))
     )
  })
```

My qplot and tplot objects are made by:

```
plot.new() 
par(mfrow=c(3,4))
barplot(df[[1]][[2]])
   *etc, etc, etc [adding more subplots to plot]*
qplot <- recordPlot()
```

Perhaps the shinyapps linux server isn't liking the recordPlot() structure; is there another way I can record my plot data and render it within the output$UI call? Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any warnings or errors in the log file on shinyapps.io? This [page](http://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html#logging) might help

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately no luck. No error messages.

Comment: Okay, maybe the [shinyapps.io mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shinyapps-users) can help if it's something specific to that platform. I know there have been issues in the past with replaying plots (in older R versions) but according to [this page](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/DisplayList/dl-record.html) it should work since R 3.3

Comment: That's quite a history! So reading through that document, I found that people were saving their recordPlot objects using saveRDS() and readRDS(). I gave this a go; I can make the rds file but when I read it into my renderPlot() structure, it gives me a "NULL value passed as symbol address" error on the UI. Any thoughts?

Comment: I haven't seen it before but someone else had a similar [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/liVwVvyxLa0) it looks like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after reading the [link provided by @ginberg](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/DisplayList/dl-record.html), I came up with this answer. Hopefully it'll help out any future readers from 2038.

First up, in the creation of my recordPlot() object, I added dev.control("enable") and dev.off(), like so:

```
plot.new() 
dev.control("enable")
hist(df etc etc etc)
qplot <- recordPlot()
dev.off()
```

Then in my server.r file, within my output$thing renderUI I changed the renderPlot to include a replayPlot(). Like so:

```
tabPanel("Q Bins", renderPlot(replayPlot(qplot), height = 600)),
```

I then uploaded the files to shinyapps - works perfectly. Thanks to ginberg for showing me the page on recording and replaying graphs.

[Other things I tried to do, but didn't get very far with:]

1. Saving the plot as an image and loading the image within the
       tabsetPanel.
2. Using plotOutput()